# Where is sda4 partition

Tags: gparted, partitioning

Below is screenshot of my ubuntu partiton, but where is sda4 ?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need it?  It's not serial or anything mine is missing sda 2 and 3!

Comment: You don't have one.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh, this is true for the primary partitions ( 1-4 ) but the extended partitions are numbered sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on *View > Device Information* in `gparted`, it should show you a side pane of how the drive is partitioned.

[image]

If the drive is partitioned with `msdos` and not `gpt` it will only support 4 primary partitions but as many logical partitions as you want contained in the extended partition.

[image]

As you can see with my setup, I only have 1 primary partition, then 1 extended, which technically you could say is a primary partition.  Then I have a swap partition in the extended partition starting at `sda5` the first logical partition.  So, if you had 3 primary partitions and 1 extended then your first 3 would be `sda1`, `sda2` and `sda3`.  If you wanted to do more, then the extended would now be `sda4` with `sda5`, `sda6` and so on in the extended partition.  Yours is showing `sda3` as the extended so by default the partitioning scheme shifts to `sda5` in the extended since it would be the next after all 4 primary partitions are used.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was going to ask the same question too, but I found the answer before posting a duplicate! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the MBR scheme, partition numbers 1-4 are dedicated to primary (or extended) partitions, whereas logical partitions are numbered 5 and up, no matter how many primary partitions exist. Furthermore, there can be gaps in primary partition numbering (say, partitions 1 and 3 might exist, but not 2 or 4). In this respect, primary partitions are something like mailboxes in an apartment building; there are always four slots, even if some of them are unused.

Logical partitions are numbered starting from 5, with no gaps. If you've got, say, logical partitions 5, 6, and 7, and if you delete 6, then 7 will become the new 6. Thus, these are numbered in a way that's more like how you'd refer to books on a shelf; there can be gaps between the books, but you'd say "the sixth book on the shelf," even if there's a big gap between it and the preceding book.

Note that this numbering system is *Linux's* way of numbering partitions. Other OSes might refer to partitions in other ways.